# What is this mysterious image?

Tags: visual, cipher, computer-puzzle

Recently, my friend who lives in Italy sent me an email. This was its contents:

> Hi,
>   I've got some news which you should be happy about. But I've seen you around on Puzzling.SE, so I though I'd make it a little harder. [Meet me here.](http://bit.ly/-0point524335)
>
> Enjoy!
>
> Regards,
>   B. Ifid

Going to the address he sent me yields this image (blown up version):

[image]

With the text:

> Ignore the white, that's nothing to you.
>   The colours are important, to solve this clue.

So, what has my friend sent me. He says it's something that I should be pleased about, and implies that he's sent me a location, but what is it.

Where should I go?

Comment: This was probably the worst-done puzzle I've ever written, but it remains my most popular...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should go to

> Heathrow Airport

As Gintas K has already noted,

> Use the rgb values of the (non-white) pixels, which stand for the ascii values of characters.

This gives you:

> LOCATIOC: rbi tcobl qq-qgixlnhro tec cqlvs umk dksvr oort lulkd dtpysq uhvx twe zirq qxs 
> - B. Ifid
> TEBAHPHPLA

The code can be solved by:

> Using the Bifid (B. Ifid) cipher. Also, the backwards letters (TEBAHPHPLA) signify that the grid used in the bifid cipher is simply the alphabet backwards (without J, as is the common method). One can use the online decrypter here: http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/bifid.php

The code is decrypted to:

> the first co-ordinates are fifty one point four seven double zero two five six, or 51.4700256

The other clue to the location comes from:

> the link to the picture: http://bit.ly/-0point524335, or -0.524335

These two clues give you

> the latitude and longitude of the location.

Comment: Marvelously done, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9):

This is the enlarged image:

[image]

As we can see it has 39 different colour pixels at the top.

> I used a colour picker tool and checked the RGB of each pixel.
>
>  I have noticed that number 32 is pretty common, which is decimal for a
>  a space character.
>
>  39 pixels = 117 characters

So we get the text:

> LOCATIOC: rbi tcobl qq-qgixlnhro tec cqlvs umk dksvr oort lulkd dtpysq uhvx twe zirq qxs
>
>
>  - B. Ifid
>
>   TEBAHPHPLA

The text looks really ugly :D

I assume there are some mistakes, OP?

> TEBAHPHPLA is ALPHPHABET in reverse (should be ALPHABET?)

also

> LOCATIOC: should be LOCATION: ?

Comment: Haha looks like that text is scary :D

Comment: @GeorgeGibson see my updated answer, am I going the right direction?

Comment: @GintasK Nice work! Looks like I'm very bad at copying long hexadecimal strings...